# Using formal parameter in built-in method calls

Tags: javascript

I want to get an element from JavaScript object.

Erroneous way is:

```
   function getColor(response)
   {
      var color = response.payload.products[0].SKUS.color;
      return color;
   }
   function getSize(response)
   {
      var size = response.payload.products[0].SKUS.size;
      return size; 
   }
```

But i want to do it in the following way

```
   function(response,color_size)
   {
      //var color_size = response.payload.products[0].SKUS+"."+color_size;
      // It is string concatenation. So i can't able to get the desired result.
      //return color_size;
   }
```

Any suggestion to do this?? Single method for getting color,size,etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getColorAndSize(response) {
  var color = getColor(response);
  var size = getSize(response);
  return {
   color:color,
   size:size
 };
}
```

Comment: I have improved the answer a little bit to reuse the previous functions. I think it's better this way, you have 3 functions to use whenever you need.

Comment: i don't have enough reputation to vote up. Thanks Andrei . I couldn't able to think of returning an object.